# Closest true value to zero in Python

Tags: python

A long time ago I read about the closest true value to zero, like `zero = 0.000000001`, something like that. In the article they mentioned about this value in Python and how to achieve it. Does anyone knows about this? I have look up here in SO but all the answers are about the closest value to zero of an array and that's not my point.

Comment: Be advised that the python implementation does not define a concept of "closest true value to zero". This means that different implementations of python (e.g. cpython, jython, etc) will have different behaviors. TLDR: This is just a technical artifact, I suggest you forget about ever having read this.

Comment: You're looking for IEEE 754. Python uses IEEE-754 64-bit floating point number for its `float` type. So the "closest" should be `1 * 2^(-1074)`, the smallest subnormalized positive number.

Comment: You can get that  number via `math.nextafter(0, 1)`.

Comment: `sys.float_info.min` has the minimum value the implementation supports that's close to zero; e.g. `2.2250738585072014e-308`.

Comment: @AlanSTACK I was just being curious :)

Comment: @sj95126: That's the minimum *normalized* value. There are denormals below that.

Comment: @iBug Python uses whatever the underlying platform provides, which is virtually universally, but not required to be, IEEE-754.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum positive denormalized value in Python3.9 and up is given by `math.ulp(0.0)` which returns `5e-324`, or `4.940656e-324` when printed with `format(math.ulp(0.0), '.7')`.